# Twice daily mysterious test emails from Sendmail.exe / WAMP server

Tags: wordpress, email, wamp, sendmail.exe

A few months ago I set up WAMP server on my Windows 7 machine to develop a Wordpress site locally. I added Sendmail.exe to make Contact Form 7 (a contact form which sends out an email from me, to me) work properly. All was well. But, on a once or twice daily basis, I receive, to the Gmail account I set up with sendmail, a "testing sendmail.exe" email. Even when my computer (running WAMP) is off. How can this be?

Once the development of the website was complete and ready to go live, I uploaded it using the Wordpress Duplicator (https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin. I have searched (using ftp) through the live site, and cannot find any kind of sendmail files there.

For client approval, I uploaded the site (again using the Worpdress Duplicator plugin) to a subdirectory on my own site, but since then I have deleted all the files from that directory.

So my question is: How on earth are theses emails getting sent? Does the sendmail application actually use some other server somewhere out there (not my WAMP "server") to send the emails, and it's got stuck in the habit of sending out this test email?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Here's the full header (I've changed my email to "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"):

```
Delivered-To: xxxxxxx@gmail.com Received: by 10.25.214.135 with 
SMTP id p7csp302451lfi; Sat, 13 Dec 2014 06:57:18 -0800 (PST) 
X-Received: by 10.181.12.17 with SMTP id em17mr16780659wid.45.1418482637935; Sat, 13 Dec 2014 06:57:17 -0800 (PST) 
Return-Path: <xxxxxxx@gmail.com> Received: from mout.kundenserver.de (mout.kundenserver.de. [212.227.126.131]) 
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id gf8si8194056wib.61.2014.12.13.06.57.17 for <xxxxxxx@gmail.com>
(version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128); Sat, 13 Dec 2014 06:57:17 -0800 (PST) 
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning xxxxxxx@gmail.com does not designate 212.227.126.131 as permitted sender) 
client-ip=212.227.126.131; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=softfail 
(google.com: domain of transitioning xxxxxxx@gmail.com does not designate 212.227.126.131 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=xxxxxxx@gmail.com;
dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com 
Received: from icpu1054.kundenserver.de 
 (infong247.kundenserver.de [212.227.29.151]) by mrelayeu.kundenserver.de  
 (node=mreue007) with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 0LbCQQ-1XXwAh0AAM-00kyHa; Sat, 13 Dec 2014 15:57:17 +0100 
Received: from 72.167.159.8 (IP may be forged by CGI script) by icpu1054.kundenserver.de with HTTP id 49vAEC-1XsTpZ40PF-017nps; Sat, 13 Dec 2014 15:57:16 +0100 
X-Sender-Info: <264661319@icpu1054.kundenserver.de> Date: Sat, 13 Dec 2014 15:57:16 +0100 Message-Id: <49vAEC-1XsTpZ40PF-017nps@icpu1054.kundenserver.de> Precedence:
```

- Paul

Comment: The headers of the email might indicate whether or not it's coming from a computer you expect or not.  Could it be email from outside your application?

Comment: Post the full headers from the email and we will have a better chance of helping you determine the origin.

Comment: Some of the header blurb contains "kundenserver.de", which seems to be associated with 1and1.co.uk (the client's web host for that website project). One of the IP addresses is also a German Kundenserver address. But it still baffles me how this could be happening. Presumably sendmail.exe cannot actually _run_ on a web server (without a lot of setting up, which I didn't do)? It's just a Windows app...isn't it?

Comment: Surely the issue will be that the `Contact Form 7` is still configured to send this email. The existance of `sendmail.exe` is irrelevant as on the live site it will be using the standard mailing functionality. So check the configuration of the WP site, that is what is sending you the email.

Comment: RiggsFolly - there is no kind of "send test email" function or setting within Contact Form 7 (that I know of). And if sendmail was not relevant, why would the email subject be "Testing sendmail.exe" and the message body be "Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!"?

Comment: I've also just run a search via ftp on the entire website for any "sendmail" files, but found nothing. A quick nose through the MySQL database didn't reveal anything out of the ordinary for a Wordpress installation.

Comment: I'm still getting these test emails, on a daily-ish basis. And I still can't figure out where they're coming from.